# ionic apps do not run in 4.x android platforms

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

After upgrading Nodejs and all other modules I can not run Ionic build apps in 4.x version of androids

it shows that application successful lunched but there is no any app installation on emulator or attached device. the same thing is in cordova

```
ionic info:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.5.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.2.2
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.5 

Npm version
{ menu: '1.0.0',
  npm: '2.11.2',
  http_parser: '2.3',
  modules: '14',
  node: '0.12.5',
  openssl: '1.0.1o',
  uv: '1.6.1',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

**update [28/06/2015]**
I tied several days but there is no success. 
I tried so many ways but the default Android target: android-22

```
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.cordova.hellocordova
        Name: HelloCordova
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-22
```

I have manipulated by config.xml but there is no success to run in 4.0.1, 4.1.2 and etc.

```
C:\Users\>adb install  android-debug.apk
2513 KB/s (2321618 bytes in 0.902s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

more details are posted in 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/507

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution 
by adding this two line in config.xml and replacin target sdk it works for me on my device.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14"/>
```